# Increase max_execution_time in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload large files to my server (my server support `post_max_size` 192mb and `max_execution_time` 600 sec). When I upload 100mb files execution will stop after 600 sec so files are not uploaded to the server. How can I increase `max_execution_time` in PHP (only for the file uploading process)? I have tried:

```
ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 1200); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Video']['tmp_name'],$tmppath)) {
  // ...
}
```

Any ideas how I can overcome this?

Comment: What *exactly* happens after 600 seconds? Which error message do you get? Upload time doesn't count against the PHP time limit

Comment: Try [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: @Ajay Chthri: for uploading some large size files you can try with some uploader like java applet uploader

Comment: same problem with me.. and it gives me "page not found" error.. i am inserting file names into a table from another table.. i am doing this in Codeignitier.. please help me

Answer (score 39):

Add this to an [htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170819/what-is-htaccess-file) (and see edit notes added below):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

Additional resources and information:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php
- https://www.looklinux.com/how-to-set-php-maximum-execution-time-in-an-htaccess-file/

---

**2021 EDIT:**

As PHP and Apache evolve and grow, I think it is important for me to take a moment to mention a few things to consider and possible "gotchas" to consider:

- PHP can be run as a module or as CGI. It is *not* recommended to run as CGI as it creates a lot of opportunities for attack vectors [[Read More]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.attacks.php). Running as a module (the safer option) will trigger the settings to be used if the specific module from `<IfModule` is loaded.
- The answer indicates to write `mod_php5.c` in the first line. If you are using PHP 7, you would replace that with `mod_php7.c`.
- Sometimes after you make changes to your .htaccess file, restarting Apache or NGINX will not work. The [most common reason for this is you are running PHP-FPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381522/php-7-php-ini-upload-max-filesize-not-working), which runs as a separate process. You need to restart that as well.
- Remember these are settings that are normally defined in your `php.ini` config file(s). This method is usually only useful in the event your hosting provider does not give you access to change those files. In circumstances where you *can* edit the PHP configuration, it is recommended that you apply these settings there.
- Finally, it's important to note that not all php.ini settings can be configured via an .htaccess file. A file list of php.ini directives can be [found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), and the only ones you can change are the ones in the changeable column with the modes **PHP_INI_ALL** or **PHP_INI_PERDIR**.

Comment: Or just change these values directly in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: @jeremy Harris, that *edited* link is now a dead end. Please update that...

Comment: The link you edited it with gives a 403 forbidden error. I will try to find another resource.

Comment: I just updated this answer with a bunch more relevant information since it seems to still get a lot of viewers even almost a decade later.

Answer (score 6):

Theres a setting `max_input_time` (on Apache) for many webservers that defines how long they will wait for post data, regardless of the size. If this time runs out the connection is closed without even touching the php.

So your problem is not necessarily solvable with php only but you will need to change the server settings too.

Comment: just now i check my server support max_execution_time 30 mints but when i upload file 30 mb file process  will stop after 10 mints (querys are not excute)

Comment: It's not the execution time you need to worry about, it's the input time. If you could upload those 30mb in less than 10min it would run. If you would upload only 200kb and need 11 min for it it wouldn't run too. It's not depending on you filesize or execution time at this moment, it's depending on the time you need to upload the file.

Comment: so we need increase to max_input_time ?

Answer (score 2):

Is very easy, this work for me:

**PHP**:

```
set_time_limit(300); // Time in seconds, max_execution_time
```

Here is the PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

For increasing execution time and file size, you need to mention below values in your .htaccess file. It will work.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
php_value post_max_size 80M
php_value max_input_time 18000
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Karvy master upload module
function uploadKarvyData()
{
    ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');  
    or
    ini_set( 'memory_limit', '1024M' );
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1024M'); 
    ini_set('max_input_time', 360000);  
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 360000);
}
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem