# Does browser timeout on huge request?

Tags: browser, upload, timeout

Assume that I use web browser to upload a huge file(maybe several GB), it may take hours for all the data to be transferred to server. Assume the server has no limit on the size of file upload, it just keeps engulfing data. Will the browser work earnestly for hours till all the data is transferred? Or browser will prompt certain error after some time? Or a browser-specific issue?

Comment: Detailed information is available at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts

Answer (score 1):

A request will always timeout at some point, regardless of the web server you are using (Apache, IIS, etc.) The defaults are usually a couple of minutes, so you will need to increase those. There are also other limits such as maximum file size that you would have to increase. An example of doing this with PHP/Apache can be found here:
[Increase max_execution_time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744107/increase-max-execution-time-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The browser will give an error page request timeout

Comment: Typically if browser waits too long for response, it will show timeout page. But will browser error out while it's still sending data to the server.