# image is not being uploaded (possibly related to its size)

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize

I have the below code for uploading an image file:

```
<?php
session_start();

If (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {

    header("location:login.php");
}

include "ConnectToDb.php";
$action = $_GET['method'];
$soruid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']);

If ($action == "image") {

    If ($_FILES['image'][name] != "") {

            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]));
            $unique = md5(microtime());
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $who = $_SESSION['username'];

            If ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
                || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
                && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 500000000)
                && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

                $pic = $unique. "." .$extension;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "answers/" . $pic);

                $ekle = "INSERT INTO `answers` (who, question_id, image, date) values('$who', '$soruid', '$pic', '$date')";
                $ok = mysql_query($ekle) or die (mysql_error());

                header("location:question.php?s=$soruid");

                }  

            }   


} elseif ($action == "text") {

    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $who = $_SESSION['username'];

    $ekle = "INSERT INTO `answers` (who, question_id, comment, date) values('$who', '$soruid', '$text', '$date')";
    $ok = mysql_query($ekle) or die (mysql_error());

    header("location:question.php?s=$soruid");


}

?>
```

If the size of the image is low, such as 10kb or something like that, upload process works without a problem, but when i try to upload a file with 3 mb of size, script stops without a hitch.

I checked the php limits such as max_post_size, memory_limit etc. and seems like no problem.

I expect the script upload the image and then redirect the page.

What is the problem?

EDIT:

If I use the below code, it works.

```
$pic = "sercan.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "answers/" . $pic);
```

So, I guess it means problem is with the code. But, Where is it?

EDIT 2:

Seems like the problem is with the if/else conditions. When I remove it, I am able to upload big-sized images.

```
If ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

..............
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are exceeding the maximum execution time (max_execution_time).

Comment: Anything useful in the logs?

Comment: Check what your upload max size in `php.ini` is set to. You can also override that in `.htaccess` . I.e: `php_value post_max_size 30M` and
`php_value upload_max_filesize 30M` or `upload_max_filesize = "30M"` and `post_max_size = "30M"`

Comment: Could it be a problem with not using `$pic = basename("$unique.$extension")`?

Comment: @iCore limit is 30 secs but script stops after 8-10 secs later which is far below than the limit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- all the values you mentioned are higher than that values.

Comment: @PHPglue not sure i understand what you mentioned, i am just started to learn PHP, but the script works for low-sized uploads. If there was a problem, maybe than you're right?

Comment: You should also test `if(isset($_FILES['image']))`, and make sure `name` is not a Constant. It should be a String.

Comment: It was an example. If your server's max upload is only 2M, then yeah, your script will stop, even when using `($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 500000000)` @Sercan

Comment: I see. I checked again, upload_max_filesize is 64M which is far below the size of the image I try to upload. Again, if I try to upload 1 Mb size image everythng is OK. But if I choose 3 Mb size of a image, it fails, script shows only a blank page.

Comment: Try to increase memory `ini_set("memory_limit","350M");` and/or see [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8744184/) about `php_value max_input_time` and other possible factors. @Sercan

Comment: Another thing which could be a factor (if you're on a hosted service) and it happened to me before, is that your `tmp` folder or `tmp` file might be full and this will prevent oversized files from being uploaded, because of too many failed attempts and has grown larger in size (temp file). @Sercan

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thanks for your interest. But, I guess the problem is with the code I use. Could you pls check the edits I made to the question?

Comment: I checked it. So now you can't use those functions. That is too bizarre. I have the very same functions in a few of my scripts, and work OK. @Sercan

Comment: The only other thing now that I see that could prevent it, is `If ($action == "image") {` which is related to a `GET` method in your code and uploading files require a POST method. @Sercan

Comment: @Fred-ii-`GET` is related with the type of the comment. Here is the latest situation: If I remove the if conditions such as `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pjpeg");` or changing `(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))` to  `(**!**in_array($extension, $allowedExts))` solves the problem. That means, type of the image is different than the allowed type. And as far as I check image is a regular JPG file created with a regular camera.

Comment: That is just very odd. I can post something below with a script that I use, and wondering if you could try it out just on its own with a 3-5MB file. However, this one will check if it already exists in the upload folder, so make sure one is not in there already; that's if you're interested, just to test out. @Sercan

Comment: @Fred-ii-Problem is absolutely related to the this code: `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"); $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]));` or `in_array($extension, $allowedExts)`. But, I am not able to figure out what is wrong with that code.

Comment: I have seen it before, and it could have something to do with the `end` and `explode`. I have a slightly different version that was a workaround of that. Let me know if you want me to post a "test" answer. @Sercan - If it does work, then you could build around it from there.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I removed that lines. Just will make a check with the MIME types. (not sure it is secure enough but I m tired of this problem) Thanks for the support.

Comment: You're welcome. I offered my code, but I will respect your wish. Cheers @Sercan

Comment: @Fred-ii-pls check the answer I've just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this code:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]));
```

To this:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");          
$bits = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension = strtolower(end($bits));
```

solved the problem.

Still not sure, How it is able to work with low-sized uploads while fails with high-sized uploads.

Whatever..

Comment: Which is 99.9% of what I was going to show you, in order to test with. This could have been avoided, had you taken me up on my offer.

Comment: Be sure, next time accepting your code offers will be the first thing I do instead of bugging around :)

Comment: Like I said in my earlier comment, I faced a similar situation and it took me the better part of a day (some time ago) to find out why it was doing the same thing that you had a problem with. It's the way the bits get exploded at the end. Certain servers will react differently and I had the misfortune of landing on such a server. I now keep seperate versions of similar scripts, should I ever need to use either one. The important thing here is, that you found your solution ;-)

Comment: I meant this `$bits = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]); $extension = end($temp);` were the lines I was going to show you, just slightly different than `$extension = strtolower(end($bits));` with the exception of the added `strtolower`

Answer (score 0):

If the file is too large, then $_FILES is empty.

So, your if statement:

```
if ($_FILES['image']) ...
```

will not fire.  Nor will your else, because that condition isn't being met.  So the script completes *without error*, even though the image size is too large, and it did not upload.

Comment: In OP's code `&& ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 500000000)` then states *"but when i try to upload a file with `3 mb` of size, script stops without a hitch."* - 3MB is far below than `500000000`

Comment: @Fred-ii- - $_FILES is empty when the size is too large.  This if statement doesn't even work, since $_FILES['image']['size'] will be empty.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I did it for fun. Even if i delete that statement, still see a blank page.