# php 7 php.ini upload_max_filesize not working

Tags: php, php-7

I have read many solutions on internet , but still cannot change `upload_max_filesize` value (`upload_max_filesize` always = 2M )

here is my loaded `php.ini` in `phpinfo()` :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path         /etc/php/7.0/apache2
Loaded Configuration File                    /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files      /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d 
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
post_max_size   8M  8M
```

here is my edited `php.ini` in  `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

```
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 86M
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 40M
```

im using ubuntu 14.04,apache2,php7.0 
(I have reset apache2 many time after each change in php.ini )

Comment: You need to check the path of php.ini, it seems you are making changes somewhere else.
You can see the ini path in phpinfo itself just check for the row 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path'

Comment: i changed every php.ini file i found , but still cannot change upload_max_filesize :(

Comment: Restart the server and check for the changes.

Comment: i have restart apache2 many times,but it still the same ...

Comment: `php -i | grep -i "upload\_max\_filesize\|post\_max\_size\|max\_file\_uploads"` is a helpful command that can help you catch that maybe whatever "ini" file you updated either hasn't been reloaded or might not be the correct file in use at all.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601191/illuminate-http-exceptions-posttoolargeexception#comment96669884_48601191

Comment: I couldn't get a file to upload through a wordpress site even though I checked all php.ini files & did everything I could think of serverside.  Turned out it was a wordpress multi-site network setting.  /wp-admin/network/settings.php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

i fingured out !

in my loaded `php.ini` config , my `error_reporting` values is `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`-> this is wrong!, so i changed it to

`error_reporting: E_ALL` and  then restart apache2 server, 
now everything working fine !

---

so please note : if `php.ini` have any error , it will use default value (which means `upload_max_filesize` always `2M` )

Comment: This was the reason. Fixed my case.

Comment: this worked, thanks. I think this is very unintuitive, i was very lucky to find your solution.

Comment: @CuongDC thank you but I still need to see my errors, how can I do that? I still get 2M though I changed my value

Comment: @AbeerSul did you restart the web server?

Comment: @CuongDC yes but it didn't fix it, thank you I finally was able to fix here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967282/why-is-php-not-allowing-me-to-upload-more-than-2mb-file/67967354?noredirect=1#comment120142756_67967354

Comment: @AbeerSul gut to know ^^

Answer (score 53):

I had a fix for PHP-FPM 7.1

Edit your php.ini in

/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini

Make changes to whatever option you want like, post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time & so...

save & close file.

run

sudo service php7.1-fpm restart

It will work!

Comment: For me, it was this simple - and it's logical. We have changed PHP variables, not Apache2.
So restarting PHP is all that was needed!

Comment: Of course! You have to restart FPM! Thank you so much! Just needed to recall that

Comment: Thank! I am so used to running as MPM where all you need is to restart apache, but since switching to FPM (for http/2 support), I didn't realize that you needed to restart FPM directly.

Comment: In my case, I just needed to edit /etc/php.ini, restart httpd. I checked for the php process (ps ax | grep -i php) and restarted that: systemctl restart php-fpm  This is on CentOS Stream.

Answer (score 26):

I had an other fix for it.
os: ubuntu 16.04
phpversion: 7.0

I created a **phpinfo.php** file containing:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

place the phpinfo.php file in the root of your website www.mywebsite.com/phpinfo.php

Navigating to it and lookup the line:

**Loaded Configuration File : /etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini**

Now you know what php.ini file is loaded.

ssh into the server and use your favorite editing tool (mine is nano) to adjust the php.ini

change the values to meet your preferences.

**post_max_size = 128M**

**upload_max_filesize = 64M**

Save and close the file.

Restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

__

check the phpinfo.ini if the new values are as set.

and if they do you are set to go.

Comment: `/etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini` should be `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`. There is no `cgi` dir in default php installation

Comment: ah some1 alr answer yes correct , just look on phpinfo(); today i wrong path by using on `php --ini` i think ...

Answer (score 10):

For `php7.2-fpm`

Ubuntu `php-fpm` located at `/etc/php/7.2/fpm` so

1. `cd /etc/php/7.2/fpm`
2. `sudo nano php.ini`
3. Search for `post_max_size = 512M` and add your fav size that you **really needed**
4. Search for `upload_max_filesize = 512M` and add your fav size that you **really needed**
5. Save File
6. And Last DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART PHP7.2-FPM to restart `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart`

Thats all!

Comment: that sudo service php7.2-fpm restart saved my life

Answer (score 7):

I am using Nginx and my solution was to restart php-fpm.

Restarting Nginx didn't do anything.

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! I'm using apache and recently moved to php-fpm - I had no idea it was a separate service!

Answer (score 6):

I also found that restarting the httpd service didn't pick up changes in the loaded configuration file (`/etc/php.ini` on Fedora 29). It's worth listing all systemd units and doing a grep for the string "php":

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | grep php
php-fpm.service
```

Restarting php-fpm did the trick for me:

```
# systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 4):

After spending hours reading forum I've resolved this way:

```
cd /etc/php
find . -name "*.ini" | xargs grep -il upload_max_filesize
./7.1/apache2/php.ini
./7.1/mods-available/better.ini
./7.1/cgi/php.ini
./7.1/cli/php.ini
./7.1/phpdbg/php.ini
./7.1/fpm/conf.d/20-better.ini
./7.1/fpm/php.ini
./7.1/embed/php.ini
```

change upload_max_filesize in **./7.1/fpm/conf.d/20-better.ini** then

```
/etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart
```

now phpinfo reports: **upload_max_filesize  10G 10G**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the best answer when you are not sure about what version/config you have.

Answer (score 4):

i also had this problem!

if you are using php-fpm service need to find php-fpm.conf and add line

`php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 100M`

for changing other type of values

```
#just for example
php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Comment: This should be chosen as best answer for who ever run using FPM sock

Answer (score 1):

Most people are forgetting to restart their php via the terminal that's why it isn't working, if you think you've done everything correctly be sure to restart your php & the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Actually I forgot to restart correctly.

**sudo service apache2 restart** is not enough

first add the configurations to **/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini** and to **/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini**
**#/php/ - then your php version here instead "7.1"**
ACtually one of these configuration file is the active one (if you want to see what use `<?php phpinfo() ?>` command in *indextest.php* file and check it on browser)
Then change these parameters on each file with what you want:

```
post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
```

And then use following command to restart the php server:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart #php<then your php version here> instead "7.0"
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart  #php<then your php version here> instead "7.1"
```

Now you should be able to see the changes of upload size. Cheers !

as shown in [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-reload-restart-php7-0-fpm-service-linux-unix/) you can get to know more about the php server controlls :

```
$ sudo service php7.0-fpmstart # <- restart it
$ sudo service php7.0-fpm stop # <- restart it
$ sudo service php7.0-fpm restart # <- restart it
$ sudo service php7.0-fpm reload # <- reload it
```

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart` fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

create two different files in the root of your project(if you are a Wordpress user,it is the root public_html folder).one is **php.ini** & the second one is **.user.ini**
and then simply add these two lines of codes in both files.

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

don't forget to restart the server.
and also make sure the user.ini file must be starting with a dot (**.**)

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was editing the wrong one. It turns out I should mondify this `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`
After doing so, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For those who have all the obvious settings mentioned in other answers and PHP file uploads are stil not working.

Check php.ini for `open_basedir` value. If a value is set (which it should be for security reasons), make sure that `/tmp` is included there. Or choose a custom value in `upload_tmp_dir` and set `open_basedir` accordingly.

Then reload the FPM service.

Answer (score 0):

I installed multiple versions of PHP on MacOS Big Sur following the steps [here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions.)

I used command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/httpd -k restart
```

to load changes made to the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

open your putty or bitvise ssh client login your server

```
sudo apt update
```

After that

```
cd /etc/php/7.4/apache2/
```

see the list to hit command below

```
ls -ltr
```

output

```
total 76
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  4 14:31 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72540 Sep  7 09:28 php.ini
```

to open php.ini enter the below command

```
 sudo nano php.ini
```

Move down Arow till not find the Below code

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

change 20MB to your desired upload size Press ctrl+s to save php.ini and exit to the editor to command prompt hot ctrl+x after that to reload apache2 hit the below command

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

For macos, check if you have a  php-memory-limits.ini file under /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/conf.d folder,

You need to update `upload_max_filesize` value in there too!