# Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I already configured php.ini file (post_max_size=10240M), but it's still throwing PostTooLargeException. How to increase upload and download limit in Laravel 5.5?

Comment: Wait you're planning to post something larger than 10gb?

Comment: Also if it's about file uploads then also change [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: `php -i | grep -i "upload\_max\_filesize\|post\_max\_size\|max\_file\_uploads"` is a helpful command that can help you catch that maybe whatever "ini" file you updated either hasn't been reloaded or might not be the correct file in use at all. Eventually I figured out that since I'm using Laradock, my values were getting overwritten: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/v7.13/php-fpm/laravel.ini

Comment: please chage /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini instead of /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini'. then try which might solve your problem

Answer (score 31):

First, check your php version

```
php --version 


PHP 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 08:44:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

if your php version is 7.2

open this file `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

Update these 2 fields to something that big enough. Ex. `1024M` or `2048M`

```
post_max_size = 1024M                                                                                                            
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

Restart the php

```
service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Done ✅

Comment: this should be `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` instead of `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini'. if you run via `php artisan serve`

Comment: yes but to show a message to the user ?

Answer (score 16):

First, check your PHP version.

```
php -v
```

The command below will print the path to the php.ini file that your server is using.

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Next.

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

The values of **post_max_size**, **upload_max_filesize** and **memory_limit** by default have the value of **8M**, **2M**, and **128M** respectively.

Search for those variables and change their values, whilst ensuring that the sizes follow the same ratio as the default values.

See example below:

```
post_max_size = 2G
upload_max_filesize = 1G
memory_limit = 3G
```

For "heavy-loaded sites", it is useful to have FPM installed and running.

```
sudo apt install php7.4-fpm -y
sudo service php7.4-fpm start
```

Finally, restart your web server.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try the following code in your `php.ini` file to increase the memory limit.

```
 ini_set('memory_limit','10240M');
 # Do your Intervention operations...
```

You may also be interested to read https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/interventionimage-memory-limit?page=1

Comment: add this line to what file ? please mention in your answer !

Comment: add to controller class.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) If you change the post_max_size from php.ini and restart the apache
>   server but after does not get proper response then you have temp solution.
>
> Handle the `illuminate-http-exceptions-posttoolargeexception` exception

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['File size is too large']);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

> and display the error in your view file

```
@if ($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone using Valet:** 
I had to set post_max_size,upload_max_filesize and memory_limit in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` instead of `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

1.first check your php version also php.ini file path by using this command

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

2.change the upload file size in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

3.reset apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or you can change the size in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error in laravel. I'm using XAMPP in Windows and I noticed I was editing incorrect php.ini file.

Check php.ini file directory by command `php --ini` in your cli.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34707473)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was php8.2 fpm php.ini issue.
I was increasing the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` in `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` only and restarting my web server. Issue wasn't resolved.

But I later increased `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` in `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` and restart php fpm service with the command

```
service php8.2-fpm restart
```

issue was solved then.