# Modify upload_max_filesize php.ini not working

Tags: php, linux, server, phpmyadmin, apache2

I've modified the php.ini file in

> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (file indicated by phpinfo())

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 55M
```

i've restart apache2, retart server, but phpinfo() and phpmyadmin are still saying 2M ...

Tanks for your help

Comment: Then that is not the `php.ini` file used by PHP. Look at the first section of `phpinfo()` output and find what `php.ini` file is actually being used look for `Loaded Configuration File `

Comment: Also as you only seem to be checking with `phpMyAdmin` look at the Alias used by `phpMyAdmin` somethimes these values are set in there

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37381522/9370144

Comment: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php5/apache2`
`Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

and i've try to comment the error_reporting, nothing changing (I restart apache2 everytimes)

Comment: Ok i figured out, there was a problem in the error reporting.

Thank you for your answers !