# Why is PHP not allowing me to upload more than 2MB file?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, file-upload

I can't upload an image more than 2MB in my website form.

I have set up the needed settings in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 100M  

.
.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = ON
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 100M
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

.
.

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

But the problem is that when I print php info in my index page I get different output :/

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Why is this happening and how can I fix it?**

**NOTE:** I'm serving my website with nginx if it matters (see nginx settings)
[image]

Comment: Try restarting nginx and the php-fpm process. If that doesn't work then check the additional configuration or the fpm pool configuration if there are any overrides to the values in php.ini

Comment: @apokryfos I tried restarting it, yes I think something is overriding my settings but I can't find the source

Comment: what is the post_max_size of your PHP ?

Comment: @KenLee its 100M as stated in the question

Comment: The default path for the fpm pool configuration is usually `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d` the default one is usually called `www.conf` and you can check (and add) overrides in this file. If you have the original file then at the end there's instructions on how you can e.g. add `php_value[post_max_size] = 100M` or something like that. Be sure you restart your php-fpm process after changing this file (this is a different process than nginx usually, if using `service` to manage services then this is restarted using `service  php7.4-fpm restart`.

Comment: @apokryfos is this the only way? I mean why do I have to go and change the default file itself?

Comment: Normally changing the php.ini should work. I'm offering this information as a means to troubleshoot where the problem may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally issue fixed:**

the solution was to add `php.ini` and `.user.ini` files in the project's public directory to set the needed values (both files):

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

like this:

[image]

I didn't find the real reason why updating `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` but these 2 files finally fixed it

Comment: I wasn't expecting this to work but it did... Using PHP 8.0 and updating the ini file it says it's got loaded from phpinfo() doesn't work, nor did .htaccess, yet somehow these 2 files together finally made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. If you're going to increase those significantly, consider upping the `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` values as well

If you can't find the source of the 2mb setting in php.ini you can override in a .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Or directly in your PHP pages if need be

```
<?php 
 ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
 ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
 ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
?>
```

for example...

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, I need to find the real source of "upload_max_filesize = 2M" in the picture and not write the code in all my forms

Comment: .htaccess in your doc root should override anything set in .ini and its just one file in one place. In fact, are you sure you don't have existin .htaccess files anywherein the path to your script that could be causing this?

Comment: I tried your suggestions but still they don't work unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

If Upper answers not fixed then try below steps:

1. create `user.ini` file into additional ini file loaded location - see `phpInfo()` to find the location path. (search keyword- Additional .ini files)
2. Insert the lines what we need to modify. Ex: `max_upload_size = 20M`
3. Save and restart apache or respective server.