# get content from url in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I want to put the content of a URL in a string and the process it. However, I have a problem.

The url is **http://138.201.123.244:8990/time/data.txt**

When I use cURL and file_get_contents in my server (cPanel), I did not receive any content!

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you open the url in a browser? Because I can't

Comment: Show us your curl/file_get_contents code.

Comment: You might be getting a 'connection refused' , did you set curl to Verbose?

Comment: Could be any number of problems.  Does your environment have cURL installed?  Is cURL version correct for use with PHP? Are there networking problems between your server and that endpoint?  Is that endpoint returning 200 response?

Comment: @ceejayoz `$file = "http://138.201.123.244:8990/time/data.txt";
        $out_result = file_get_contents($file);`

Comment: @NineBerry Yes, works fine.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, I tried many methods but I did not answer.

Comment: @Mohammad But "Did not answer means" what?  Your server could not reach the target site (i.e. some sort of network issue)? Your server can reach the target site, but your request is timing out? Your the target server returns unexpected response?  There are too many possible problems here to give you an answer without you narrowing it down with steps you have taken to investigate the problem.

Comment: @MikeBrant I get 200 response. I've tested code another server but result is the same.

Comment: @Mohammad Then is sounds like target endpoint is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case this isn't a configuration problem with your server this code should work:

```
<?PHP
    $my_URL="http://138.201.123.244:8990/time/data.txt";

    $lines = file($my_URL);

    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
    {
            echo $line_num." ".$line;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You code result: 
`Warning: file(http://138.201.123.244:8990/time/data.txt): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/pishroar/public_html/bots/t.php on line 4
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pishroar/public_html/bots/t.php on line 6`

Comment: @Mohammad I tested this code as well and it works as expected. It outputs a single line with this base64 image. The Invalid argument is a result of the timeout. You should increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini or .htaccess to prevent this timeout. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744107/increase-max-execution-time-in-php

Comment: @Mohammad I'm sorry to hear that. I think that this is mainly a server timeout problem you've got there. Maybe you could adjust this question and mention the timeout so someone wiser then my could answer you.