# File upload not working, if the file is not uploaded within 25-30 sec

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-upload, laravel-4

I have an AWS ec2 server setup which is running php 5.6.40 and has following settings

```
max_execution_time : 3000
max_file_uploads : 50
max_input_time : 600
max_input_vars : 1000
post_max_size : 1000M
upload_max_filesize : 100M
```

but the file upload is not working. I have putted a simple die in the controller function which displayed when small files are uploaded. but shows ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when using large files greater than 324KB.

I have debugged the code fully it has some conditions in most situations if the file is uploaded successfully within 25-30 seconds the later code runs successfully if the internet is little fluctuating and not able to upload 324KB it shows me an error for that also. I have also checked there is nothing wrong with the code it is working fine on other server.

[image]

I have fetched the values of ini in the PHP code so that I get the exact value after overwrite through `ini_get_all()`

Comment: check security group for ec2 inbound

Comment: @Vivek `80 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔`

Comment: increase max_execution_time. Your current time is 30sec. make it 1 min and try again. You can refer here to change time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744107/increase-max-execution-time-in-php

Comment: also restart apache after changing in php ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution the issue is with the apache. I have apache 2.4.39 installed and it is not including the setting in the httpd.conf in installation so need to put it manually and restart the server.

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40, MinRate=500 body=20, MinRate=500
```

Thanks to the AWS support for this help.