# Unable to upload "large" files, both file_exists() and is_uploaded_file() are false

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a gif file to my server using an upload tool (ShareX)

It works very well with "small" files, but when trying to upload a 8 MB one (takes about 1 minute with my connection), it just doesn't work.

So I did some quick debug, and it seems that the functions `file_exists` and `is_uploaded_file` are both set to false, exactly like nothing was uploaded, which isn't the case.

```php
if (!file_exists($_FILES[$fileFormName]["tmp_name"]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileFormName]["tmp_name"]))
{
    error([
        "error" => "No file uploaded",
        "file_exists" => file_exists($_FILES[$fileFormName]["tmp_name"]),
        "is_uploaded_file" => is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileFormName]["tmp_name"])
    ], "400 Bad Request");
}
```

Why would that happen?

My apache2 php.ini `upload_max_filesize` is set to `128M` so it shouldn't be a file size issue.

My apache2 php.ini `max_execution_time` is set to `0` so it shouldn't be a timeout issue.

I wasn't able to find anything similar to my problem using Google.

Comment: File uploads are usually implemented using a HTTP POST request. So you also need to adjust `post_max_size` accordingly.

Comment: @arkascha Hello and thanks for your answer, I saw this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744184/12730904 at the same time you posted your comment, I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I also had to adjust [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in my php.ini file.