# How to increase maximum upload filesize for uploading vidoes using php.ini file in VPS server ubuntu

Tags: php, php-ini

I built an education website and it provides courses with large videos. And I built a videos uploader. But I Can not even upload a 4-mins videos.

I increased the following three parameters:

upload_max_filesize = 50G

memory_limit = -1

post_max_size = 100G

This is my PHP.INI FILE:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = /home/programming-ocean/tmp

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 50G

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Comment: Why can't you? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, I do not get an error, But it takes so much time and at the end it does not upload the video and the page stops execution

Comment: Are you getting an HTTP status code from the server?

Comment: Max execution time could possibly be an issue; Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744107/increase-max-execution-time-in-php